# How to change the configure command for PHP

Tags: linux, php

I need to enable Freetype for PHP's GD, and I'm getting absolutely nowhere trying to figure out how. According to [this](http://www.lampdocs.com/blog/2008/04/freetype-support-for-directadmin-fast-and-easy/) article I need to change the configuration command, but I have no clue where to find this file! I've been searching for hours and I'm really not getting anywhere, if anyone could help (or even set me on the right path to help myself) it'd be much appreciated. Thanks!

Our server is using CentOS release 5.8.

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using? The `./configure ...` command is used when compiling PHP, and the exact method varies greatly depending on distro used.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, I'm new to this networking thing so you may have to bear with me here :P I ran `dmesg | head -1` and somewhere in there it said Red Hat... Is that right?

Comment: It *could* be Red Hat (RHEL), but it might also be CentOS or Fedora... But they both are based on RHEL, so I guess the instructions would be the same on all three. You could also check the contents of `/etc/redhat-release` and/or `/etc/os-release`, if they exist. Finally, if you purchased the server, the Linux distro should have been mentioned in the server information.

Comment: `redhat-release` worked, we're using CentOS release 5.8. Thanks!

Comment: It's an old question but I found a nice tutorial for it. Please see over here: http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-how-to-recompile-php-with-gd-support-on-a-live-serv-1572.html it might help other people.

Answer (score 1):

The "configuration command", `./configure`, is run when compiling PHP. To change configure flags you have to download the PHP source then recompile it with the flags you need

How did you install PHP (from source or with a package manager?). If via a package manager, you should check `phpinfo()` for Freetype support since packagers usually enable most configure flags. You can also check your package manager for other PHP packages since one of them can have this flag enabled

Comment: I checked phpinfo(), and no, Freetype is not enabled. PHP came installed with the server when we purchased it so I didn't have to set anything up there. Are you saying if I reinstall PHP as if it were never installed in the first place, I can somehow modify the configure string then?

Comment: @ACobbs: You have to uninstall PHP before you can install it again. Search your package manager [I have no experience with rpm] for a package named `php`, or `php5.X` or something similar and uninstall it. Then get the source from [the official website](http://php.net/downloads.php) and install it. You can also try to get a newer php version (if available) through rpm